# Exchange routing change advice

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, alfresco

I need some tips advice how to configure Exchange 2003 so that:

Internal users users@domain.com send an email to *any*@servername

All emails directed at @servername will be routed to another (local network) mail server system (in combination with Alfresco) on servername which will handle it further

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a SMTP connector for that address space and configure it to relay messages to the server which will handle them:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265293/en-us
http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/configuring-smtp-connector.html